# Using unsigned number types with Javascript backend

Tags: javascript, kotlin, numbers, unsigned

I'd like to use Kotlin's unsigned number types with the Javascript backend; that is, I'd like to write Kotlin code using `UByte` and compile that to JS.

I've written the following test program:

```
@kotlin.ExperimentalUnsignedTypes
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val x : UByte = 1u
    println(x)
}
```

I can compile and run it no problem with the JVM backend:

```sh
$ kotlinc-1.3.70/bin/kotlinc hello.kt -include-runtime -d hello.jar
$ java -jar hello.jar 
1
```

But if I compile it to Javascript and try to load the output into a browser, it fails:

```
$ kotlinc-1.3.70/bin/kotlinc-js hello.kt -output hello.js
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Unsigned</title>
    <script src="kotlin.js"></script>
    <script src="kotlin.meta.js"></script>
    <script src="hello.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am not even trying to call `hello.main`, it fails on page load already:

```
Uncaught TypeError: UByte is not a constructor
    at main (hello.js:8)
    at hello.js:12
    at hello.js:15
```

In case it helps, the generated JS is as follows:

```js
if (typeof kotlin === 'undefined') {
  throw new Error("Error loading module 'hello'. Its dependency 'kotlin' was not found. Please, check whether 'kotlin' is loaded prior to 'hello'.");
}var hello = function (_, Kotlin) {
  'use strict';
  var UByte = Kotlin.kotlin.UByte;
  var println = Kotlin.kotlin.io.println_s8jyv4$;
  function main(args) {
    var x = new UByte(1);
    println(x);
  }
  _.main_kand9s$ = main;
  main([]);
  Kotlin.defineModule('hello', _);
  return _;
}(typeof hello === 'undefined' ? {} : hello, kotlin);
```

**What am I missing to work with `UByte` et al. in Kotlin code that compiles to Javascript?**